# How to manage my own scripts

Tags: best-practices, scripting

Every administrators, developers have their own collection of scripts (some patterns). Time to time they are dismissed from one job and they are employed to other one. Is there any good, easy used, indexed tool to collect the common used sql scripts (structured folder/file system as a default)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started to play with [RedGate's tool - Script Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-scripts-manager/). You can have them together in a single place with some UI. It may worth a try :).

Comment: it looks good, are you using it? is it good enough?

Comment: For me it's nice enough :). Didn't use it for long.. just one two weeks of play, but looks solid enough.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL*Plus, the Oracle command line too, you can use the syntax:

```
SQL> @http://blah.com/myscript.sql
```

And run all your scripts off your own personal webserver if you like. My good friend Vishal does [this](http://vishalgupta.com/oracle/sqlscripts/). You just need to get a VM or something of your own, these are cheap now, a quick Google shows £10/month.

Just be certain it doesn't stipulate in your contract that your employer owns any scripts you write while working for them...

Comment: ..and employer owns your life. :)  I meant so scripts like attach/ detach database, move database...reindex, common optimization scripts...NO any employer specific code.

Comment: @igor: just added a link to a friend of mine who I learned this technique from

Comment: as a variant...to store on own website (increases web site traffic + good enough storage) thanks! it is a good idea: knowledge sharing.